# Interpolate values and replace with NaNs within a long gap?

Tags: python, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate data with gaps. Sometimes the gap can be very large, and I do not want the interpolation to "succeed" within the gap; the result should be `NaN`s inside a large gap. For example, consider this example data set:

```py
orig_x = [26219, 26225, 26232, 28521, 28538]
orig_y = [39, 40, 41, 72, 71]
```

which has clear gap between x-values 26232 and 28521. Now, I would like to have the `orig_y` interpolated to x-values like this:

```py
import numpy as np 

x_target = np.array(range(min(orig_x) // 10 * 10 + 10, max(orig_x) // 10 * 10 + 10, 10))
# array([26220, 26230, 26240, 26250, 26260, 26270, 26280, 26290,
#        ...
#       28460, 28470, 28480, 28490, 28500, 28510, 28520, 28530])
```

and the output `y_target` should be `np.nan` everywhere else than at `26220`, `26230` and `28520`. Let's say that the condition for this would be that if there is a gap larger than `40` in the data, the interpolation should result to `np.nan` inside this data gap.

#### Goal shown as a picture

Instead of this

[image: not this]

Get something like this

[image: but this]

*i.e.* the "gap" in the data should result to `np.nan` instead of garbage data.

#### Question

What would be the best way (fastest interpolation) to achieve this kind of interpolation? The interpolation can be linear or more sophisticated (e.g. cubic spline). One possibility I have in mind would be to use the [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) as starting point like this

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f = interp1d(orig_x, orig_y, bounds_error=False)
y_target = f(x_target)
```

and then search for gaps in the data and replace the interpolated data with `np.nan` inside the gaps. Since I will be using this on fairly large dataset (~10M rows, few columns, handled in parts), performance is a key.

Comment: Interesting question. Would it suit you the purposes of the graph to make it a dashed line instead of a solid one? Maybe of your data saw more than n NaNs it overlayed the dashed line?

Comment: In the graph there is no line at all; there is just very dense scatterplot, which resembles a line :)

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, a think I got a "fast enough" implementation using basic [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) and [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) for speedups. Forgive for writing everything in the same loop and same function, but it seems that is the numba way of making your code fast. (numba loves loops, and does not seem to accept nested functions)

#### Test data used

I added some mode data to `x_target` to test the algorithm performance.

```
orig_x = np.array([26219, 26225, 26232, 28521, 28538])
orig_y = np.array([39, 40, 41, 72, 71])

x_target = np.array(
    np.arange(min(orig_x) // 10 * 10,
              max(orig_x) // 10 * 10 + 10, 0.1))
```

#### Test code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y_target = interpolate_with_max_gap(orig_x, orig_y, x_target, max_gap=40)

plt.scatter(x_target, y_target, label='interpolated', s=10)
plt.scatter(orig_x, orig_y, label='orig', s=10)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

#### Test results

The data is interpolated in regions with gap less than `max_gap` (40):
[image: test results]

closeup:

[image: closeup]

**Speed**:
I first tried a pure python + numpy implementation, which took 49.6 ms with the same test data (using `timeit`). This implementation with numba takes 480µs (100x speedup!). When using `target_x_is_sorted=True`, the speed is 80.1µs!

The `orig_x_sorted=True` did not give speedup, probably since the `orig_x` is so short that sorting it does not make any difference in timing in this example.

#### Implementation

```py
import numba
import numpy as np

@numba.njit()
def interpolate_with_max_gap(orig_x,
                             orig_y,
                             target_x,
                             max_gap=np.inf,
                             orig_x_is_sorted=False,
                             target_x_is_sorted=False):
    """
    Interpolate data linearly with maximum gap. If there is
    larger gap in data than `max_gap`, the gap will be filled
    with np.nan.

    The input values should not contain NaNs.

    Parameters
    ---------
    orig_x: np.array
        The input x-data
    orig_y: np.array
        The input y-data
    target_x: np.array
        The output x-data; the data points in x-axis that
        you want the interpolation results from.
    max_gap: float
        The maximum allowable gap in `orig_x` inside which
        interpolation is still performed. Gaps larger than
        this will be filled with np.nan in the output `target_y`.
    orig_x_is_sorted: boolean, default: False
        If True, the input data `orig_x` is assumed to be monotonically
        increasing. Some performance gain if you supply sorted input data.
    target_x_is_sorted: boolean, default: False
        If True, the input data `target_x` is assumed to be 
        monotonically increasing. Some performance gain if you supply
        sorted input data.

    Returns
    ------
    target_y: np.array
        The interpolation results.
    """
    if not orig_x_is_sorted:
        # Sort to be monotonous wrt. input x-variable.
        idx = orig_x.argsort()
        orig_x = orig_x[idx]
        orig_y = orig_y[idx]

    if not target_x_is_sorted:
        target_idx = target_x.argsort()
        # Needed for sorting back the data.
        target_idx_for_reverse = target_idx.argsort()
        target_x = target_x[target_idx]

    target_y = np.empty(target_x.size)
    idx_orig = 0
    orig_gone_through = False

    for idx_target, x_new in enumerate(target_x):

        # Grow idx_orig if needed.
        while not orig_gone_through:

            if idx_orig + 1 >= len(orig_x):
                # Already consumed the orig_x; no more data
                # so we would need to extrapolate
                orig_gone_through = True
            elif x_new > orig_x[idx_orig + 1]:
                idx_orig += 1
            else:
                # x_new <= x2
                break

        if orig_gone_through:
            target_y[idx_target] = np.nan
            continue

        x1 = orig_x[idx_orig]
        y1 = orig_y[idx_orig]
        x2 = orig_x[idx_orig + 1]
        y2 = orig_y[idx_orig + 1]

        if x_new < x1:
            # would need to extrapolate to left
            target_y[idx_target] = np.nan
            continue

        delta_x = x2 - x1

        if delta_x > max_gap:
            target_y[idx_target] = np.nan
            continue

        delta_y = y2 - y1

        if delta_x == 0:
            target_y[idx_target] = np.nan
            continue

        k = delta_y / delta_x

        delta_x_new = x_new - x1
        delta_y_new = k * delta_x_new
        y_new = y1 + delta_y_new

        target_y[idx_target] = y_new

    if not target_x_is_sorted:
        return target_y[target_idx_for_reverse]
    return target_y
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here is how I do this:

```py
def gappy_interp(xint, x0, y0, *, maxgap=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Interpolate as nuumpy.interp, but fill np.NaN is gaps of x0 that are
    greater than *maxgap*.

    xint : array-like
        The x-coordinates at which to evaluate the interpolated values.
    x0 : 1-D sequence of floats
        The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing if argument
        period is not specified. Otherwise, xp is internally sorted after
        normalizing the periodic boundaries with x0 = x0 % period.
    y0 : 1-D sequence of float or complex
        The y-coordinates of the data points, same length as x0.
    maxgap : float
        maximum gap size in xint to interpolate over.  Data between gaps is
        filled with NaN.
    **kwargs :
        Passed to `numpy.interp`.

    """

    yint = np.interp(xint, x0, y0, **kwargs)

    # figure out which x0 each xint belongs to:
    x_index = np.searchsorted(x0, xint, side='right')
    x_index = np.clip(x_index, 0, len(x0)-1)

    # figure out the space between sample pairs
    dx = np.concatenate(([0], np.diff(x0)))
    # get the gap size for each xint data point:
    # get the indices of xint that are too large:
    index = (dx[x_index] > maxgap)

    # this is fine, except the degenerate case when a xint point falls
    # directly on a x0 value.  In that case we want to keep the data at
    # that point.  So we just choose the other inequality for the index:

    # as above, but use side='right':
    x_index = np.searchsorted(x0, xint, side='right')
    x_index = np.clip(x_index, 0, len(x0)-1)
    dx = np.concatenate(([0], np.diff(x0)))
    index = np.logical_and(index, (dx[x_index] > maxgap))

    # set interpolated values where xint is inside a big gap to NaN:
    yint[index] = np.NaN

    return yint
```

I haven't benchmarked it, but you shouldn't need to resort to numba to make this fast because it uses `searchsorted`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem, found this question and would like to share my solution (which I think is much easier):

This was your code to interpolate everywhere, including the gap:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import copy as cp

orig_x = [26219, 26225, 26232, 28521, 28538]
orig_y = [39, 40, 41, 72, 71]
x_target = np.array(range(min(orig_x) // 10 * 10 + 10, max(orig_x) // 10 * 10 + 10, 10))

# interpolate y (default: kind=linear)
fy = interp1d(orig_x, orig_y, bounds_error=False)
y_target = fy(x_target)
```

To find out where `target` is too far away from `orig` you can do a similar interpolation of `x` itself but using nearest neighbor and calculate the difference:

```
# interpolate x (kind=nearest neighbor)
fx = interp1d(orig_x, orig_x, bounds_error=False, kind='nearest')
dx = x_target - fx(x_target)
```

Now you can easily use `dx` to remove data within the gap:

```
# remove interpolated data in gap
y_target_clean = cp.copy(y_target)
y_target_clean[np.abs(dx)>40] = np.nan
```